# Как лучше сделать таблице в БД

Tags: база-данных

У меня есть юзер и у него есть роль. Кол-во ролей ограничено и очень мало(15-20).
Лучше у каждого пользователя хранить его роль или создать дополнительную таблицу ролей и хранить в них сами роли, а у юзеров сохранять только айдишники этих ролей. Я нашел много разной литературы, но хотелось бы задать этот вопрос и здесь. Если будет не сложно ответьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Непонятно, что в данном случае есть "роль". Потому как с точки зрения дизайна что ИД, что имя - один хрен. А также непонятно, существует ли возможность возникновения в будущем новых, не существующих сейчас, ролей...

Comment: @Akina, такая возможность точно существует, что такое роль? Это поле в одной таблице бд, таблица размером 100000 записей, а ролей всего 15-20

Comment: 1) Если список может измениться, придётся отбросить ENUM/SET тип. Впрочем, на него сильно никто и не рассчитывал. 2) Т.е. это просто некий атрибут с фиксированным набором значений? В таком случае таблица значений и FK из основной таблицы - единственное разумное решение. Если, конечно, нет каких-то экзотических операций на этом поле - например, необходимость составного индекса с участием значения этого поля.

Answer (score 1):

Чем меньше количество запросов к БД для достижения одного и того же результата, тем эффективнее работа приложения в целом (в вакууме). Если можно одним запросом забрать данные о юзере и о его роли, то можно и в одной таблице хранить. Даже лучше.

Для более точного ответа нужно видеть и понимать взаимодействие данных внутри приложения.